# Run if a file is changed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to run a particular job if a particular file has been changed.

Consider the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
- test

always:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  script:
    - env | sort

change:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
          - dir/file
  script:
    - echo "dir/file"
```

If I modify and commit to the default (`main`) branch:

- the `dir/file`, it triggers both the `always` and `change` job
- any other file it will trigger only the `always` job

as expected.

Instead If I modify and commit to any other branch (ie create a merge request) it will run both jobs even if I do not modify the `dir/file` file.

To summarise:

- [x] modify and commit `dir/file`: `always` and `change` jobs run
- [x] modify and commit **not** `dir/file` file: only `always` job run
- [ ] using the WebUI modify **not** `dir/file`, commit to new branch: `always` and `change` jobs run

Am I missing something?

Thanks

## Update 1

```yaml
stages:
- test

always:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  script:
    - env | sort

change:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        paths:
          - dir/file
  script:
    - echo "dir/file"
```

Same as above:

- [x] modify and commit `dir/file`: `always` and `change` jobs run
- [x] modify and commit **not** `dir/file` file: only `always` job run
- [ ] using the WebUI modify **not** `dir/file`, commit to new branch: `always` and `change` jobs run

Comment: Is it a job launched by the merge request or the commit in the branch ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use the WebUI, make a modification to a file (not `dir/file`), commit to a new branch, even before creating the merge request, a new pipeline is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the indentation.

It is:

```yaml
change:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
          - dir/file
        ^^ # this is important
```

> If I modify and commit to any other branch (ie create a merge request)

Second, you can add additional criteria:

```yaml
change:
  stage: test
  image: alpine
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        paths:
          - dir/file
        ^^ # this is important
```

That would exclude the case where a file is changed as part of a merge request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the actual pipeline I have the space you are suggesting before `- dir/file`. Regarding your second suggestion, I would like to filter the job in any case, push to main, push to other branches, ...

Comment: @yellowhat Then it should only be triggered if that file is changed.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I want, in any case if `dir/file` file is changed run this job, that's why I did not have the `if` only `changes`

Comment: The code in the open post, works if I push to `main` but it does not for other branches

Comment: @yellowhat OK, the "even if I do not modify the dir/file file" was the part which would apply to other branches then.

Comment: If I modify the `dir/file` file I expect the job to run, as it is, but if I do not modify it runs anyway.

Comment: @yellowhat even with additional condition?

Comment: What do you mean by additional condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249009/discussion-between-vonc-and-yellowhat).

Comment: Add `Update 1` and still same behaviour